# In Android Java/Kotlin, does implementing an interface give it direct access to the nesting class's local variables

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In Android Java/Kotlin, does implementing an interface give it direct access to the nesting class's local variables. More specifically, when accessing the nesting class's local variables are they passed by value or reference to the interface.

Comment: Could you please add a code example to illustrate what you are talking about.

Comment: Your question is too much embracing, be more specific.

Comment: you can pass a  callback to the nested class method. for example:`foo({it})`. the it is the local variable that the nested method call the callback and pass the local variable into lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear to me whether you mean "fields in the outer class" or "locals in the enclosing method", but tl;dr is "everything is by reference". (Well, obviously primitives aren't by reference, but everything else.)

---

A local inner class holds a reference to the outer class. For example,

```java
// Java
public class Outer {
    public class Inner implements Supplier<Outer> {
        @Override public Outer get() {
            return Outer.this;
        }
    }
}
new Outer().new Inner().get();
```

```
// Kotlin
class Outer {
    inner class Inner: () -> Outer {
        override fun invoke() = this@Outer
    }
}
Outer().Inner().invoke()
```

The `Outer$Inner` class has a compiler-generated final field named `this$0` (which the compiler also generates code for filling in at construction time) which is what `Outer.this`/`this@Outer` actually refers to.

Accessing fields in the outer class, for example

```java
// Java
public class Outer {
    String string = "";
    public class Inner implements Supplier<String> {
        @Override public String get() {
            return string;
        }
    }
}
new Outer().new Inner().get();
```

```
// Kotlin
class Outer {
    var string: String = ""
    inner class Inner: () -> String {
        override fun invoke() = string
    }
}
Outer().Inner().invoke()
```

is translated to go through the reference to the outer, e.g. `Outer.this.string`/`this@Outer.string`. Ditto with method calls on the outer.

---

An anonymous inner class has the same features as a local inner class for referencing the outer class, plus also having access to local variables in the scope where they were created.

```java
// Java
public class Outer {
    public Supplier<String> inner(final String string) {
        return new Supplier<String>() {
            @Override public Outer get() {
                return string;
            }
        }
    }
}
new Outer().inner("").get();
```

For references to `final` local variables, the Java compiler generates a final field to hold them and fills them in during construction of the inner class. References to non-`final` local variables are not allowed in Java.

Kotlin does that for `val` (e.g. final) variables, and additionally allows referencing `var` (e.g. non-final) variables.

```
// Kotlin
class Outer {
    fun inner(string: String): () -> String {
        var string2 = string
        return { string2 }
    }
}
Outer().inner("").invoke()
```

If a `var` variable is ever used by an anonymous inner class, the Kotlin compiler converts *every* access of it to go through a `kotlin.jvm.internal.Ref` wrapper. A reference to this wrapper can be passed around just like a reference to final variables. If you use the Kotlin plugin in IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio, the IDE will underline the variable name to indicate that this wrapping is happening automatically.

---

None of the above was Android-specific, it is Java and Kotlin (JVM) behavior. (Kotlin JS and Kotlin native have different implementations but the observable behavior is still the same.)